# Swift - Size of content view does not match with UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have an iOS app with a `TableView`, all UI of the app are done programmingly with `autolayout` using `Swift`.

All UI are working great until recently, I have to add a new component (custom `UIView`) inside the `UITableViewCell` which cell height will be changed when the new component is shown or hidden. The height of the cell is not correct so my views inside the `UITableViewCell` become a mess.

After checking the Debug View Hierarchy, I found that the height of the `UITableViewCell` is different than then `UITableViewCellContentView`.

When the component should display:

- Table view cell has correct height (Longer height)
- Content View of `UITableViewCell` is shorter then expected (the height is correct if component is hidden)

When the component should hidden:

- Table view cell has correct height (Shorter height)
- Content View of `UITableViewCell` is longer then expected (the height is correct if component is display)

I am not really sure what is the real issue. When I toggle the component to be displayed or not, I do the followings:

```
// Update the constraints status
var componentIsShown: Bool = .....
xxxConstraints?.isActive = componentIsShown
yyyConstraints?.isActive = !componentIsShown

// Update UI
layoutIfNeeded()
view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.endUpdates()
```

It seems to me that when I toggle the component to be displayed or not, the `UITableViewCell` is updated immediately, but content view used previous data to update the height. If this is the issue, how could I update the content view height also?

If this is not the issue, any suggestion to fix it or do further investigation?

Thanks

====================

Updated in 2018-08-29:

Attached are the codes for the issue.
Clicking on the topMainContainerView in MyBaseView (the view with red alpha bg) will toggle the hiddenView display or not.

In ViewController.swift:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    var cell: MyViewCell

    if let theCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as? MyViewCell
    {
        cell = theCell
    }
    else
    {
        cell = MyViewCell(reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

    cell.setViewCellDelegate(delegate: self)
    return cell
}
```

MyViewCell.swift

```
class MyViewCell: MyViewParentCell
{
    var customView: MyView

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        return nil
    }

    override init(reuseIdentifier: String?)
    {
        customView = MyView()

        super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        selectionStyle = .none
    }

    override func initViews()
    {
        contentView.addSubview(customView)
    }

    override func initLayout()
    {
        customView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        customView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        customView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        customView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        customView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    override func setViewCellDelegate(delegate: MyViewCellDelegate)
    {
        super.setViewCellDelegate(delegate: delegate)
        customView.delegate = delegate

        customView.innerDelegate = self
    }
}
```

MyViewParentCell.swift:

```
protocol MyViewCellDelegate
{
    func reloadTableView()
}

protocol MyViewCellInnerDelegate
{
    func viewCellLayoutIfNeeded()
}

class MyViewParentCell: UITableViewCell
{
    private var delegate: MyViewCellDelegate?
    var innerDelegate: MyViewCellInnerDelegate?

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        return nil
    }

    init(reuseIdentifier: String?)
    {
        super.init(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        selectionStyle = .none

        initViews()
        initLayout()
    }

    func initViews()
    {
    }

    func initLayout()
    {
    }

    override func layoutSubviews()
    {
    }

    func setViewCellDelegate(delegate: MyViewCellDelegate)
    {
        self.delegate = delegate
    }
}

extension MyViewParentCell: MyViewCellInnerDelegate
{
    func viewCellLayoutIfNeeded()
    {
        print("MyViewParentCell viewCellLayoutIfNeeded")
        setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
        layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

MyView.swift

```
class MyView: MyParentView
{
    private var mainView: UIView

    // Variables
    var isViewShow = true

    // Constraint
    private var mainViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
    private var hiddenViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

    private var hiddenViewPosYHideViewConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
    private var hiddenViewPosYShowViewConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

    // Constant:
    let viewSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.width

    // Init
    override init()
    {
        mainView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: viewSize, height: viewSize))

        super.init()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        return nil
    }

    override func initViews()
    {
        super.initViews()

        topMainContainerView.addSubview(mainView)
    }

    override func initLayout()
    {
        super.initLayout()

        //
        mainView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        mainView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topMainContainerView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        mainView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topMainContainerView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        mainView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topMainContainerView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        mainView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: viewSize).isActive = true
        mainView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: viewSize).isActive = true
        mainViewHeightConstraint = mainView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: viewSize)
        mainViewHeightConstraint?.isActive = true
    }

    override func toggle()
    {
        isViewShow = !isViewShow
        print("toggle: isViewShow is now (\(isViewShow))")
        setViewHidden()
    }

    private func setViewHidden()
    {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            if self.isViewShow
            {
                self.hiddenViewBottomConstraint?.isActive = false
                self.hiddenViewTopConstraint?.isActive = true
            }
            else
            {
                self.hiddenViewTopConstraint?.isActive = false
                self.hiddenViewBottomConstraint?.isActive = true
            }

            self.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.needsUpdateConstraints()
            self.innerDelegate?.viewCellLayoutIfNeeded()
            self.delegate?.reloadTableView()
        }
    }
}
```

MyParentView.swift

```
class MyParentView: MyBaseView
{
    var delegate: MyViewCellDelegate?
    var innerDelegate: MyViewCellInnerDelegate?

    override init()
    {
        super.init()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        return nil
    }

    override func initViews()
    {
        super.initViews()
    }

    override func initLayout()
    {
        super.initLayout()        
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }
}
```

MyBaseView.swift

```
class MyBaseView: UIView
{
    var topMainContainerView: UIView

    var hiddenView: UIView

    var bottomActionContainerView: UIView
    var bottomSeparator: UIView

    var hiddenViewTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var hiddenViewBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

    // Layout constratint
    var descriptionWidthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var moreMainTopAnchorConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var moreMainBottomAnchorConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var separatorTopAnchorToActionBarConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var separatorTopAnchorToPartialCommentConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

    // Constant
    let paddingX: CGFloat = 10
    let InnerPaddingY: CGFloat = 9

    init()
    {
        topMainContainerView = UIView()

        hiddenView = UIView()

        bottomActionContainerView = UIView()
        bottomSeparator = UIView()

        super.init(frame: .zero)

        initViews()
        initLayout()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        return nil
    }

    func initViews()
    {
        let borderColor = UIColor.gray

        backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 211/255.0, green: 211/255.0, blue: 1, alpha: 1)

        topMainContainerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.7)
        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(toggle))
        topMainContainerView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)

        // Hidden View
        hiddenView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        hiddenView.layer.cornerRadius = 50

        // Action
        bottomActionContainerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        bottomSeparator.backgroundColor = borderColor

        // Add hiddenView first, so it will hide behind main view
        addSubview(hiddenView)
        addSubview(topMainContainerView)
        addSubview(bottomActionContainerView)
        addSubview(bottomSeparator)
    }

    func initLayout()
    {
        // MARK: Main
        topMainContainerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        topMainContainerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
        topMainContainerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        topMainContainerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
        topMainContainerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true

        // Hidden View
        hiddenView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        hiddenViewTopConstraint = hiddenView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topMainContainerView.bottomAnchor)
        hiddenViewTopConstraint?.isActive = true
        hiddenView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        hiddenView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
        hiddenViewBottomConstraint = hiddenView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topMainContainerView.bottomAnchor)
        hiddenViewBottomConstraint?.isActive = false
        hiddenView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true

        // MARK: Bottom
        bottomActionContainerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        bottomActionContainerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: hiddenView.bottomAnchor, constant: InnerPaddingY).isActive = true
        bottomActionContainerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        bottomActionContainerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        bottomActionContainerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32).isActive = true

        // MARK: Separator
        bottomSeparator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        separatorTopAnchorToPartialCommentConstraint = bottomSeparator.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomActionContainerView.bottomAnchor, constant: InnerPaddingY)
        separatorTopAnchorToActionBarConstraint = bottomSeparator.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomActionContainerView.bottomAnchor, constant: InnerPaddingY)
        separatorTopAnchorToPartialCommentConstraint?.isActive = false
        separatorTopAnchorToActionBarConstraint?.isActive = true
        bottomSeparator.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        bottomSeparator.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        bottomSeparator.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10).isActive = true
        bottomSeparator.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        self.hiddenViewBottomConstraint?.isActive = false
        self.hiddenViewTopConstraint?.isActive = true
    }

    @objc func toggle()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to show your cell class.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri Sorry for late reply. The cell class in my code is complicated, I tried to provide a simple version of the cell class, but the issue does not appear in the simple version, so I am still investigation for the exact issue.

Comment: Then post the actual issue because people are taking time out of their day to solve your problem. And if you post a problem that doesn't exist, it is a waste of both your and the contributor's time. _no offense_

Answer (score 2):

The layout of contentView is not updating. You should try

```
cell.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Try and share results.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found that I should call `super.layoutSubviews()` in MyViewParentCell.swift or simply remove the function to fix the issue.

```
override func layoutSubviews()
{
    super.layoutSubviews()
}
```